# How can i destructure this in such a way that i get an array with every month data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a json structure,

```
"meterConsumption": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-01-01",
                        "actual": 200,
                        "predicted": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2012-01-02",
                        "actual": 250,
                        "predicted": 250
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2012-01-31",
                        "actual": 200,
                        "predicted": 190
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-02-01",
                        "actual": 200,
                        "predicted": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-02-02",
                        "actual": 250,
                        "predicted": 245
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2012-02-29",
                        "actual": 270,
                        "predicted": 270
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-12-01",
                        "actual": 200,
                        "predicted": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-12-02",
                        "actual": 200,
                        "predicted": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2020-12-31",
                        "actual": 300,
                        "predicted": 300
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

these array of objects can be ranging from month 1 - 12 or it can be of any random months.
i need to write a function that would extract the data from it and give it in this format

```
[
   [
      {
         "month":1,
         "timestamp":"2020-01-01",
         "actual":200,
         "predicted":200
      },
      {
         "month":1,
         "timestamp":"2020-01-02",
         "actual":250,
         "predicted":250
      },
      {
         "month":1,
         "timestamp":"2020-01-31",
         "actual":200,
         "predicted":190
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "month":2,
         "timestamp":"2020-02-01",
         "actual":200,
         "predicted":200
      },
      {
         "month":2,
         "timestamp":"2020-02-02",
         "actual":250,
         "predicted":240
      },
      {
         "month":2,
         "timestamp":"2020-02-29",
         "actual":270,
         "predicted":270
      }
   ]
]
```

i need to pass extract data in such a way, also need suggestion if the structure seems fine because i will use these data to plot chart in my react app

Comment: what have you tried? No code attempt is shown in the question.

Comment: What happened with December? And what you tried so far to solve this on your own? A `.reduce()` call would most likely be enough to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

No, destructuring alone cannot do that. You're mapping, not just extracting. The map function can do that:

```js
let mapped = [original[0].meterConsumption.map(({month, details}) =>
    details.map(x => ({month, ...x}))
)];
```